# UWP. Работа с несколькими экранами

Tags: c#, uwp, desktop

Всем привет, стала интересна возможность работы с несколькими экранами из UWP (такое вообще реально).
Есть задача: написать приложение, которое при подключении компьютера к двум (допустим) экранам открывалось на всех экранах и выводило разные окна (для каждого экрана своя инфа).

Comment: Попробуйте `ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync` для показа нового окна (Application view) и `ProjectionManager.StartProjectingAsync` для отправки этого окна на другой монитор. Мне не на чем попробовать.

Comment: Примерный код есть здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42364350/6766879